# Merging right & left signals to mono with op amp?

Tags: audio, radio, transmitter

Sorry for my english i'm a young french.

I want to design an audio transmitter to connect my pc to my Hi-Fi without Jack cables.

For now i just want to send a mono signal because sending a stereo seems to be too complicated and i don't need it.

The problem is that my PC's output is a stereo jack. So is it correct to merge the two signals in once, using an operational amplifier in buffer or summing ? Will the sound be ok, just suming two signals ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think Aspect Oriented Programming is appropriate for audio signals...

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need an opamp. You can do it easily enough this way:

[image: Passive Mixer]

This will sound fine although the volume level will be lower than normal -- so you will likely need to turn up the volume knob on your Hi-Fi.

Comment: Suggest R3=47K pot, R4=0...

Comment: I agree with @Brian (FYI)

Comment: @BrianDrummond why 47K pot only ?

Comment: With R4 > 0, you can't fade right down to 0 volume. Other values will work if that doesn't matter.

Comment: @Brian But he's connecting to a Hi-Fi system so it would have final output authority, no? I'm thinking the pot is just for level adjustment to prevent saturating the Hi-Fi input.